# How to connect another object (or user) to Django views (add_to_cart)

Tags: django, django-views, e-commerce

I am trying to develop an e-comm site. Where parents buy stuff for kids. Parent add children to his/her profile:

```
class Kid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    last_name =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    province = models.CharField(choices=PROVINCE_CHOICES, max_length=2, default='AB')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    school =  models.CharField(max_length=120)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Also, I have OrderItem and Order classes, taken from a tutorial and it works. I have added **kid** object to OrderItem, maybe I need to add it to Order too.

```
 class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kid = models.ForeignKey(Kid, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}' 
    

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In views, I have a define **add_to_cart**:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
        )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, 
        ordered=False
        )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity +=1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "Quantity of " + item.title + " was updated.")
            return redirect('/menu/')
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, item.title +" was added to your cart.")
            return redirect('/menu/')
    else:
        event_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            event_date=event_date
            )
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, item.title +" was added to your cart.")
        return redirect('/menu/')
```

I think I need to add **kid** object somewhere here like:

```
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        **kid=???
        ordered=False
        )
```

but have no idea how.
It would be good if I have a page of a child with a button **Make Order**, which opens a list of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url path of add_to_cart to also accept the slug of a kid:

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('add_to_cart/<str:kid>/<str:item>', add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    ...,
]
```

in views.py:

```
def add_to_cart(request, kid_slug, item_slug):
    kid = get_object_or_404(Kid, slug=kid_slug)
    item = get_object_or_404(MenuItem, slug=item_slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        kid=kid,
        ordered=False
    )
    ...
```

In the kid page template, supposing you have a `kid` object instance variable:

```
{% url 'add_to_cart' kid.slug item.slug %}
```